# VBA searching sheets for value and write them to cell

Tags: vba

I tried a lot but i cant find the mistake. I'm quite sure that it is just a small one....

I want to search a specific column of all of the sheets except the "Fileupload" sheet for a value which is in the Fileupload sheet. If it is in a specific range  the value should be written in a cell.
It throws the object variable or with-blockvariable not determined error. Or it breaks down.....

```
Sub forEachWs()
        Set FileUpload = Worksheets("FileUpload")
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim FileUpload As Worksheet

        cntsheet = 0

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "FileUpload" Then
                For i = 1 To ws.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
                    For j = 1 To worksheets("FileUpload").Range("E9").End(xlDown).Row
                        If ws.Cells(1, 2 + i).Value < ((FileUpload.Cells(5, j + 8).Value) + (FileUpload.Cells(3, 5).Value) * 0.001) And ws.Cells(1, 2 + i).Value > ((FileUpload.Cells(5, j + 8).Value) - ((FileUpload.Cells(3, 5).Value) * 0.001)) Then
                            Worksheets("FileUpload").Cells(7 + cntsheet, j + 8) = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
                        End If
                    Next j
                Next i
                cntsheet = cntsheet + 1
            End If
        Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `Tabelle2`?

Comment: its the Fileupload sheet sry. edited it

Comment: ok, that's better; what line throws the error?

Comment: its the if block

Comment: You have 2 If statements - which one? (what's the exact line?) - when it throws the error click the Debug button and it'll take you to the exact line with the problem (it should be highlighted)

Comment: Sry. Its the second if statement.

Comment: If ws.Cells(1, 2 + i).Value < ((FileUpload.Cells(5, j + 8).Value) + (FileUpload.Cells(3, 5).Value) * 0.001) And ws.Cells(1, 2 + i).Value > ((FileUpload.Cells(5, j + 8).Value) - ((FileUpload.Cells(3, 5).Value) * 0.001)) Then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to add...

```
Set FileUpload = Worksheets("FileUpload")
```

... after the first line? I.e.:

```
Sub forEachWs()
    Dim FileUpload As Worksheet
    Set FileUpload = Worksheets("FileUpload")
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    cntsheet = 0

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "FileUpload" Then
            For i = 1 To ws.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
                For j = 1 To Worksheets("FileUpload").Range("E9").End(xlDown).Row
                    If ws.Cells(1, 2 + i).Value < ((FileUpload.Cells(5, j + 8).Value) + (FileUpload.Cells(3, 5).Value) * 0.001) And ws.Cells(1, 2 + i).Value > ((FileUpload.Cells(5, j + 8).Value) - ((FileUpload.Cells(3, 5).Value) * 0.001)) Then
                        Worksheets("FileUpload").Cells(7 + cntsheet, j + 8) = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
            cntsheet = cntsheet + 1
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to put Dim FileUpload As Worksheet before Set FileUpload = Worksheets("FileUpload"). Does that work?

Comment: Wonderfull!
It fills the wrong cells but this i will fix on my own^^

Comment: No problem, you could also neaten up the code by replacing instances of Worksheets("FileUpload") with just FileUpload (other than when you actually set FileUpload). Once you get to your loops, they're referring to the same thing. :)